# Add Items To ListBox In UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have a Listbox that exists in an UpdatePanel on an ASP.NET webform. Also inside the UpdatePanel, exists a Button that adds a bunch of ListItem's to the Listbox, this PostBackTrigger as shown below:

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSection6" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Run Scan" ID="btnEditSectionStory6" runat="server" OnClick="btnRunScan_Click" />
        <br />
           <asp:ListBox ID="lbLog" runat="server" Height="263px" Width="747px"></asp:ListBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEditSectionStory6" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I add items in the click event:

```
 protected void btnRunScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbLog.Items.Add("Scan Beginning...");

.....hundreds of other items
}
```

The items are added to the ListBox, however it is after the entire btnRunScan_Click method is run, rather than adding them as each event occurs (So the user can receive messages as the actions occur). Am I missing an attribute or something on the UpdatePanel?

TIA

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You place controls inside an UpdatePanel and then attach a PostBack trigger. Unless there are more controls inside `updSection6` that shown here that is completely useless. But what do you mean by "entire btnRunScan_Click method is run"? If you are expecting that items show up one by one in the ListBox?. That is not how it works.

Comment: You latter comment is correct. I was looking for a way to add items one by one rather than carte blanche at the end of the btnRunScan_Click method

Comment: Webforms does not work that way. Only when all the code is done running is the updates html send to the browser. If you want this you will need an Ajax solution with a webservice.

Comment: IOW, controls that cause a postback (like the LinkButton) *are* triggers, if they are inside an update panel; you only need to add a trigger if they are outside the update panel. And, a postback will post the *entire* page, every time. If the postback occurs inside an update panel (or by a trigger), only the html inside the update panel will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

To Add Items without refreshing page or prevent from calling the cyclic events use following code and eliminate postBackTrigger inside the Trigger.Use following code that is tested working for me.Also use the scriptManager to prevent from exception over to use the updatePanel

.aspx design file

```xml
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSection6" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
            </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Run Scan" ID="btnEditSectionStory6" runat="server" OnClick="btnRunScan_Click" />
            <br />
               <asp:ListBox ID="lbLog" runat="server" Height="263px" Width="747px"></asp:ListBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.cs file

```
protected void btnRunScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbLog.Items.Add("Scan Beginning...");
}
```

As other also mention you can also use jquery with ajax to code over the client side to do this one.