# I can't get values of Listbox in asp.net after it was daynamically added in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I daynamically create options of select in javascript, and click a asp:Button to submit the added options. but i can't get that from ListBox. pls help me!!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Hello.aspx.cs" Inherits="BeyondInfo.Hello" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Welcome to My First ASP.NET</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add() {
            var count = document.getElementById("count");
            if (count.value == "") {
                count.value = 1;
            }
            count.value = parseInt(count.value) + 1;
            var num = count.value;
            var listBox2 = document.getElementById("ListBox2");
            var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
            optn.value = num;
            optn.text = num + "_add";
            listBox2.options.add(optn);

        }

    </script>
</head>
<link href="Common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="height: 277px">
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>b1222222222222222222222222222</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>b2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>b3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>b4</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>
            <input id="count" type="hidden" />
            <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="ADD" onclick="add()"/>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
</p>
```

Hello.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Hello : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sel = "";
        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox2.Items) {
            sel +=item.Text + ",";
        }
        Label1.Text = sel;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do that using JS and webforms, you'll have to use the AJAX control pane of the [AJAX control toolkit](http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try to use your way, but firstly, can you tell me what wrong with that code.

Comment: Well the ListBox Id won't be `ListBox`, it'll be some autogenerated value. `document.createElement("OPTION")` won't work because you also need to add the option to the ViewModel and you can't do that client side. This is why you need to use the Ajax control toolkit. TBH, why are you learning webforms? Webforms is pretty much defunct technology these days. MVC is the newer equivalent.

Comment: Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540353/add-items-to-listbox-in-updatepanel)

Comment: thanks for your help, from what you answer,maybe i need to to learn more about Aps.net.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this post answer by NC01. You may be able to achieve what you want by doing something similar.

Basically they store the added fields in a hidden field so they are accessible server side.

> I believe that your problem is that when you add an item to a DropDownList client-side (using JavaScript) that when a PostBack occurs, the item will disappear. The only way around this is to add a hidden server-control to the page and when adding the item client-side, add it to the hidden server-control also, so that when a PostBack occurs you can also add it server-side.

Here's an example.

https://forums.asp.net/t/1287204.aspx?How+to+add+the+values+to+listbox+control+using+javascript

```
aspx file:

<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
 <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server">
  <asp:listitem value="1">Item 1</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="2">Item 2</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="3">Item 3</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="4">Item 4</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="5">Item 5</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="6">Item 6</asp:listitem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
 <input id="DropDownList1NewItems" type="hidden" name="DropDownList1NewItems" runat="server">
 <input type="button" onclick="addItem();" value="Add Item">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function addItem()
{
 // Add the item here...
 var ddlRef = document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>');
 var newOption = window.document.createElement('OPTION');
 newOption.text = 'SomeNewItem';
 newOption.value = 'SomeNewItem';

 ddlRef.options.add(newOption);

 var hiddenElementRef = document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList1NewItems.ClientID %>');

 if ( hiddenElementRef.value.length > 0 )
  hiddenElementRef.value += ';';

 hiddenElementRef.value += 'SomeNewItem';
}
// -->
</script>

aspx.cs file:

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 if ( this.IsPostBack )
 {
  if ( DropDownList1NewItems.Value.Length > 0 )
  {
   string [] newItemsArray = DropDownList1NewItems.Value.Split(';');
   for (int i=0; i<newItemsArray.Length; i++)
   {
    string newItem = newItemsArray[i];

    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(newItem, newItem));
   }

   DropDownList1NewItems.Value = string.Empty;
  }
 }
}
```